# Is there any solution to display selected records from popup to select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

1. I have one select dropdown.
2. If any option selected from dropdown so one popup will display.
3. I just want if user selected value from popup so that value should display on the select field.
4. value shoud display from that select field which is generating popup box.
   Here is my code.

```js
$("#select-me").on('change', function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $("#myModal_first").modal('show');
    }else if($(this).val() == 2) {
      $("#myModal_second").modal('show');
    }
   });
```

```css
.modal {
   text-align: center;
   }
   @media screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
   .modal:before {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   content: " ";
   height: 100%;
   }
   }
   .modal-dialog {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
   .modal.show .modal-dialog {
   width: 100% !important;
   }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="ftco-section contact-section ftco-degree-bg">
   <div class="container bg-light">
      <div class="row block-9">
         <div class="col-md-12 pr-md-12">
            <form method="post" id="backtestForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="select-me">
                     <option value="1">Moving Average</option>
                     <option value="2">Exponential Moving Average</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="myModal_first" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                     <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <div class="modal-content">
                           <div class="modal-body">
                              <input type="text" name="simple_moving_average" id="simple_moving_average" class="form-control" placeholder="TEXT">
                           </div>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xl-6 text-center" style="align-self: center !important;">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="myModal_second" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                     <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <div class="modal-content">
                           <div class="modal-body">
                              <div class="row block-9">
                                 <div class="col-md-6 pr-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <select class="form-control" id="#">
                                          <option>SELECT THE OPTIONS</option>
                                          <option value="open">OPEN</option>
                                          <option value="close">CLOSE</option>
                                          <option value="low">LOW</option>
                                          <option value="high">HIGH</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-6 pr-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <select class="form-control" id="#">
                                          <option>SELECT THE OPTIONS</option>
                                          <option>1</option>
                                          <option>2</option>
                                          <option>3</option>
                                          <option>4</option>
                                          <option>5</option>
                                          <option>6</option>
                                          <option>7</option>
                                          <option>8</option>
                                          <option>9</option>
                                          <option>10</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xl-6 text-center" style="align-self: center !important;">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
               </div>
            </form>
            <?php echo "<h1>Hello</h1>"; ?>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

As you can see it. I have the problem is after value selected from popup so those record should display on select field which is generating the popup.

Comment: there is nothing to do with php or codeigniter, I changed that tags to html and css you will get beter result.

Comment: Looking something like this ? https://codepen.io/bobbiejwilson/pen/qrjgKE

Comment: thanks for replying. i have seen the given url it is exact the my problem but i want the solution of how i can display value after selected value from the popup.

Comment: Sorry ! I dont understand this **display value after selected value from the popup** do you want to select user values in popup modal or you want to display next user values in popup which is selected  ?

Comment: @Dilek please run code snippet where you see a select dropdown. Now if you select any option from select dropdown then one popup will display. now if you enter some value then you have to click save button. after clicked save button those value should display somewhere right. so i want those value should display on that select dropdown only. hope you get my point now.

Comment: do you want to close modal after submit ? or you want new fields display in modal select list

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got from your answer, modal will close after submition done in 3 seconds, you need to create a php page and change this `Your_php_submit_page.php` to your created page for insert data from modal.
when modal close then submited data will be displayed on main select list.
if you dont want to close modal, and want to show submited data in select box in modal then you need to remove this function `setTimeout` totaly in ajax.

here we go Ajax :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#SecondForm').submit(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var formValues = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
  url:"Your_php_submit_page.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:formValues,
  dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data){
    if(data.error === 'ok'){
     $('#SecondForm').hide();
     $('#result').html('<p class="success">All gone well modal will close after 3 seconds.<p>');
     setTimeout(function() {
     $('#myModal_second').remove();
     $('.second2').remove();
     window.location.reload();
     }, 3000);
    } else {
     $('#result').html(data.error);
     $('#SecondForm')[0].reset();
    }
   }
  });
 }); 
 $('#change').change(function(){
   var title = $(this).val();
   $('#myModal_second').modal('show');
 });
});
```

```css
.modal {
   text-align: center;
   }
   @media screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
    .modal:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    }
   }
   .modal-dialog {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }
    .modal.show .modal-dialog {
    width: 100% !important;
   }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="ftco-section contact-section ftco-degree-bg">
   <div class="container bg-light">
      <div class="row block-9">
         <div class="col-md-12 pr-md-12">
            <form method="post" id="backtestForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
     <select id="change">
       <option value="">Select One</option>
       <option value="this">This</option>
       <option value="that">That</option>
     </select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="myModal_first" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                     <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <div class="modal-content">
                           <div class="modal-body">
                              <input type="text" name="simple_moving_average" id="simple_moving_average" class="form-control" placeholder="TEXT">
                           </div>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xl-6 text-center" style="align-self: center !important;">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="myModal_second" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                     <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <div class="modal-content second2">
                           <div class="modal-body">
                              <div class="row block-9">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Our Modal title</h4>
        <form id="SecondForm">
                                 <div class="col-md-6 pr-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <select class="form-control" id="#">
                                          <option>SELECT THE OPTIONS</option>
                                          <option value="open">OPEN</option>
                                          <option value="close">CLOSE</option>
                                          <option value="low">LOW</option>
                                          <option value="high">HIGH</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-6 pr-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <select class="form-control" id="#">
                                          <option>SELECT THE OPTIONS</option>
                                          <option>1</option>
                                          <option>2</option>
                                          <option>3</option>
                                          <option>4</option>
                                          <option>5</option>
                                          <option>6</option>
                                          <option>7</option>
                                          <option>8</option>
                                          <option>9</option>
                                          <option>10</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
       </form>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xl-6 text-center" style="align-self: center !important;">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
               </div>
            </form>
            <?php echo "<h1>Hello</h1>"; ?>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/uch3n8v6/)